# VB/C#: View Compiler Command-Line Generated by IDE

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction

I'm using MS VS2010. How could the VB/C# compiler command-line generated by the IDE be viewed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable verbose logging in Visual Studio. See this article on MSDN regarding verbose logging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx

You enable this in visual studio like this: go to Tools > Options > Project and Solutions > Build and Run and change values of "MSBuild project build output verbosity"